# Lost answers (during server migration?)

Tags: support, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question I asked dissappeared](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/476/question-i-asked-dissappeared)

A couple of answers and comments that I wrote a few hours ago have mysteriously disappeared from the site. Does this have anything to do with the server migration that's in progress? Will my answers be restored from a backup?

Comment: Someone noted the same issue at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68452/content-missing-after-data-center-move

Comment: I responded http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68452/content-missing-after-data-center-move - lets us know if you'd like us to dig your posts up or if it's not too much trouble just repost.

Answer (score 2):

[I asked this question also.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/476/question-i-asked-dissappeared)

The answer:

> There's a chance that the post was
>   lost during the data-centre migration,
>   but I'm not on the development team so
>   I don't know what processes were in
>   place (if any) to prevent this.
>
> [Blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/datacenter-migration-oct-23/) about migration.
>
> *ChrisF*

And in the comments to it:

> @john this is probably it – Jeff Atwood♦

And I can speak from experience that your answers probably aren't coming back.