# Question I asked dissappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, questions

I asked a question(on meta) last night about my reputation, "Why Isn't My Reputation Updating?", but today I can't find it.  It's not listed with my questions(on meta).  A search doesn't find it.  Was it deleted?  Migrated?  If so, shouldn't I have been notified?

Interestingly enough, I had theorized that the server move might have affected my reputation too.  My reputation doesn't show any of the upvotes I've received in the past few days.  And what about votes on meta?  Since the meta rep is from the parent site, do votes on meta have any effect?

*This is sort of two questions.  I'll split it into two if anyone thinks it necessary.*

**UPDATE:** [I decided to ask the question again.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/480/why-isnt-my-reputation-updating)

Comment: I can verify this. I saw your question yesterday and upvoted it.

Comment: Votes on meta do have an effect - they earn badges if you get enough. I'd post a separate question about your main site rep.

Comment: @ChrisFL: That's just it.  I *did* post a separate question.  And now it's gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a chance that the post was lost during the data-centre migration, but I'm not on the development team so I don't know what processes were in place (if any) to prevent this.

[Blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/datacenter-migration-oct-23/) about migration.

Comment: I think that's probably what happened.  In that case it's no big deal, just annoying.

Comment: The old site is still up and running and can be accessed by changing your hosts file, useful in case you really lost quite some text.

Comment: @john this is probably it